# How to download file over a url in java

Tags: java, spring, download

I have a webapp which is hosted locally (Windows). My application needs to download certain files stored in C:\mydownloaddirectory.

I have used apache commons-io's FileUtils.copyURLToFile(Url source, File destination) - the issue here is that my downloads is coming from C:...
So, I can't do something like

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL("C:\mydownloaddirectory\myfile.txt"), ...)
```

This is not a valid protocol.

So, what other way can I make my app download over the browser? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a valid protocol: "file://....": https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fileurl.html

Comment: thanks @duffymo, this works fine, but what if I want it to download over the browser for other users connected to this local machine?

Comment: Then you need an Http listener and a web url.